# How can I get the value for href from a js function?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, href

I have the below code:

```
<a href="#">launch</a>
```

and I have the value which is to be substituted in the place of '#' received from a function call in Javascript. Let's say the value is 'www.google.com' and is stored in the variable `abc` in the function `url();`.

Is there any way I can replace the '#' dynamically with the variable value from the function?

Please do help me out. Many thanks!

Comment: Its going to be a lot easier if you have an `id` or a `class` on your anchor tag. Cn you show what JavaScript code you currently have?

Comment: Hello @putvande,
here's the js snippet;

Comment: Hello @putvande,
here's the js snippet;

`var abc = 'mailto:'+dom2+'?subject='+tempsubj2+'&cc='+ccvl;`

i want thus value of abc to come instead on '#'

Comment: I have myself found a simple way to solve this problem.
what i did was, i altred the code from:
`<a href="#">launch</a>`
to
`<span id=test><a href="#">launch</a></span>`

and in java-script, i called like this:

`var abc = 'www.google.com';`
`document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '<a href="'+abc+'">launch</a>';`

and i got the result which i was expecting! This just changed the entire line of code instead of '#' which anyway did the job..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` attribute in your HTML:

```
<a id="some-id" href="#">launch</a>
```

Then, in your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('some-id').href = 'new-href'
```

`document.getElementById()` gets the DOM object with the specified id. `.href` access the target of the anchor tag, a property of the DOM object.

[Further reading.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: This is clearly the most detailed answer, why this deserves a downvote I have no clue.

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question. OP wants to replace the attribute value, not (just) access it.

Comment: @putvande there, done. Blame the bad title.

Comment: This answer gave me another Idea, and that made me solve the issue!

Comment: here's what I did;
I altred the code from:
`<a href="#">launch</a>`
to
`<span id=test><a href="#">launch</a></span>`

and in java-script, i called like this:

`var abc = 'www.google.com';`
`document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '<a href="'+abc+'">launch</a>';`

and i got the result which i was expecting! This just changed the entire line of code instead of '#' which anyway did the job..!!

Answer (score 2):

here is another way to do this, using jquery

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Comment: thats why i wrote "here is another way to solve"

Comment: @REHANSHIKKALGAR this is not clearer or more concise than the default version

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery:

```
document.querySelector('a').href = yourVar;
```

Comment: This only works if the link is the first one on the page. If you make assumptions, at least mention them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setAttribute`

```
<a href="#" id="link">launch</a>

document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an id then you could do this:

```
 <a id="myLink" href="#">launch</a>
```

And using jQuery(This is using JQuery, not exactly pure JavaScript syntax):

```
var hrefResult = $("#myLink").attr("href")
```

Comment: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Comment: @FelixKling you are right, this is more a JQuery answer, I've edited my answer and this is just other option